# item insert into certain list index on Python 2.7.15

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm experiencing the following issue

```
a = ['Alivn','Bob','Carry','Sammy','Dary','Amy']
c = [1,3,5]
d = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

I want to insert `d` list into `a` list automatically with `c` list as indexes.

Such as, When inserting a item into `a` list,

`'aaa'` will be inserted index 1 of `a`.

`'bbb'` will be inserted index 3 of `a`.

`'ccc'` will be inserted index 5 of `a`.

Generally, I know a simple way is `a.insert(1,d[i])`, 
but this is not what I want because the actual list `a` has 500~1000 elements.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'd use: [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Hmm... Upon further reading you're looking to do more. I suggest subclassing `list` Although where the heck are the values for `c` coming from? Speaking of... what's the meaning of `d`?

Comment: @Jaba `c` is the list of indices OP wants to be inserted at, `d` is the list of values to be inserted to said indices

Comment: oic, well took me a couple re-reads but yes you're right, you are a good reader

Comment: Can you provide a final output of `a`? Is it something like `['Alivn','Bobaaa','Carry','Sammybbb','Dary','Amyccc']`?

Comment: @Banghua,  the final output of a: ['Alivn','aaa','Bob','Carry','bbb','Sammy,'Dary','ccc','Amy]

Answer (score 2):

The way you have this set up, to insert into *specific indices* you'll need to specify those manually. Using your list approach, as you've indicated:

```
for idx, val in zip(c,d):
   a.insert(idx, val)
```

Where [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will put the two lists together as a list of tuples.

Comment: if applying the way you suggested, the final output is ['Alivn', 'aaa', 'Bob', 'bbb', 'Carry', 'ccc', 'Sammy', 'Dary', 'Amy']. If I want  ['Alivn', 'aaa', 'Bob', 'Carry', 'bbb', 'Sammy', 'Dary', 'ccc', 'Amy'], I must modify c = [1,4,7], but c = [1,3,5], right?

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment of clarificaiton, you want the final output of `a` as `['Alivn','aaa','Bob','Carry','bbb','Sammy,'Dary','ccc','Amy]`. Here is the solution:

```
a = ['Alivn','Bob','Carry','Sammy','Dary','Amy']
c = [1,3,5]
d = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']

for i, index in enumerate(c):
    a.insert(i+index, d[i])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['Alivn', 'aaa', 'Bob', 'Carry', 'bbb', 'Sammy', 'Dary', 'ccc', 'Amy']
```

Comment: Why would you insert into `a` at `i + index`? That means inserting at 1, 4, 7, not 1, 3, 5.

Comment: @ShadowRanger According to the author's last comment.